# How to train and test nlu model in RASA inside Docker?

Tags: docker, rasa-nlu, rasa

Having issues with trainig RASA inside Docker.
I enter it:
`docker run -it -v C:\Users\User\Documents:/app --entrypoint=/bin/bash rasa/rasa`

Then I provide a command line to train with exact path to traning_data (it exists!)
`rasa train --data %cd%\data\split_train\train_data.md nlu`
But every time I got this

```
2019-12-16 17:35:39 WARNING  rasa.cli.utils  - '%cd%datasplit_traintrain_data.md' does not exist. Using default value 'data' instead.
2019-12-16 17:35:39 WARNING  rasa.cli.utils  - 'nlu' does not exist. Using default value 'data' instead.
```

What should I do to finally be able totrain and test my utterances in C:\Users\User\Documents\data\split_train\training_data.md?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute `rasa train` inside the running docker container.

check your running containers by executing:

```
docker ps
```

now execute rasa train inside the container with your model :

```
docker exec <container-name> rasa train <arguments>
```

test if the model was trained:

```
docker exec -it <container-name> rasa shell <arguments>
```

Reference to docker exec in the [Docker Docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/).

See also the Rasa Docs [Running Rasa with Docker](https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/running-rasa-with-docker/).